# SelectControl doesn't work in OpenLayers using IE8

Tags: jquery-ui, internet-explorer-8, openlayers

I'm trying to display an alert message when a user clicks on one of the vectors is in the vector layer. This works fine in all browser, except IE8.

```
    map = new OpenLayers.Map(id, {
        theme: null
    });

    vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Vector Layer");

    map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
    selectControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(vectorLayer);

    vectorLayer.events.on({
        'featureselected': onPopupFeatureSelect,
        'featureunselected': onPopupFeatureUnselect
    });

    map.addControl(selectControl);
    selectControl.activate();

    // ...

    function onPopupFeatureSelect(feature) {
        alert("OK");
    } // <-- Exceptions are thrown here
```

Whenever the `onPopupFeatureSelect` function is finished (at {) the IE8 debugger somehow falls into the JQuery code and throws exceptions there.

Am I using the select feature correctly?

Update: The crash occurs when I click anywhere in the map. It is not related to the popup feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery in combination with VML was causing this problem. I updated to version 1.7.1 and everything is working fine.

More information here: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7071